# Suppress zsh: command not found

Tags: macos, zsh

Is there a way to suppress the `command not found` error in MacOS/ zsh for a command typed after hash `#` symbol?

Typically, any command typed after `#` is ignored in Ubuntu/bash shell. Is there an easy way to do the same in MacOS/zsh terminal? Or equivalent character to ignore the command without resulting in the error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`zsh` has a shell option, `INTERACTIVE_COMMENTS`, which is unset (off/disabled) by default, meaning that the `#` is not treated as a comment character in interactive shells (it's still a comment character for shell script files). You can set it with…

```
setopt INTERACTIVE_COMMENTS
```

…or by using its shortcut letter, `k`…

```
set -k
```

If you always want this behavior, you can add either of those commands to the appropriate shell startup script for your situation.

`bash` actually has the same/similar option, but in most `bash` installations, it's set (enabled) by default. It seems typical `zsh` installations default to having it unset (disabled).